# Running .jar file from terminal (macOS Big Sur)

Tags: java, javafx, terminal, jar

I'm trying to run the Legv8 simulator for this class which is a .jar file. I was asked to download the JRE and I have done so. When I run the java -jar legissFX071.jar command in my desktop directory in terminal (where the .jar file is saved on its own- not in another folder) I get the "could not load or find main class" error as shown in the image attached.

The error message mentions JavaFX which does not show up when I check the version of Java I have installed. I understand this is a path or a class path issue but I don't really understand how this works. Can someone help me with the commands I can use to run the file?  Running the .jar file by double clicking it does not work.

[image: Error message I receive]

[image: Version of Java I have]

Comment: JavaFX needs to be downloaded separately and added to your classpath.

Comment: Since java 9 javafx is not bundled.

Comment: I downloaded JavaFX SDK 11.0.2 -but now how do I add it to the path?

Comment: I have been trying to use this link https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx to run the file but I do not understand how to make it work for my case specifically.

Comment: @student6060 can you please explain how your particular case differs from the one in those instructions?

Comment: I ran export PATH_TO_FX=path/to/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib  when I then run javac --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules javafx.controls legissFX071.jar  I get errors saying the javafx.controls module is not found and the class name legissFX071.jar is accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested.

Comment: @student6060 1) you're trying to run your jar with `javac` instead of `java`. 2) try `java --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules javafx.controls -cp legissFX071.jar fully.qualified.name.of.your.main.class` where `fully.qualified.name.of.your.main.class` is the *fully qualified* name (i.e. including the package) of the class that contains your `main` method.

Comment: My second error from the last comment was resolved but the javafx.controls module was still not found.

Comment: When I try to run the same command without adding the controls module I get the same could not find or load main class error that I'm talking about in the main post.

Comment: "I ran `export PATH_TO_FX=path/to/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib`". Presumably you replaced `path/to/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib` with the actual path to the JavaFX SDK?

Comment: I'm very new to this syntax. I was following the link posted previously (as a comment) so I didn't necessarily replace anything.